SharePoint Webhook Not Providing Detailed Info on File Moves
I'm using a SharePoint webhook and Sharepoint REST Api to sync two document libraries. The webhook notifies me of changes in the source library, and I use SP.ChangeQuery to retrieve change logs. My goal is to replicate changes such as Add, Update, Rename, MoveAway, MoveInto, etc., in the target library.
However, I'm encountering an issue with the Move operation. When I move a file or item, the webhook notifies me of a Rename event rather than a MoveAway or MoveInto event. Additionally, the change log doesn’t provide detailed information, like the old file path, which I need to replicate the change accurately.
My Questions:

Why does a Move operation trigger a Rename event instead of MoveAway or MoveInto?
How can I retrieve the old file path or source location when an item is moved?
Are there any recommended practices or workarounds for handling Move operations using SharePoint REST Api ?

Here is what GetChanges endpoint return me:
[{
            "odata.type": "SP.ChangeItem",
            "odata.id": "https://sharepoint-url/sites/MyCustomSite/_api/SP.ChangeItembb194d80-e790-4a7e-a7a2-d0aad70de12e",
            "odata.editLink": "SP.ChangeItembb194d80-e790-4a7e-a7a2-d0aad70de12e",
            "ChangeToken": {
                "StringValue": "1;3;069a9217-3a20-4242-8e7f-d024bdbf09e2;638646104605230000;219234"
            },
            "ChangeType": 4,
            "SiteId": "c1086585-8a88-4d0c-81e4-1ed0e3f5aef4",
            "Time": "2024-10-15T17:34:21Z",
            "Editor": "",
            "EditorEmailHint": null,
            "ItemId": 43,
            "ListId": "069a9217-3a20-4242-8e7f-d024bdbf09e2",
            "ServerRelativeUrl": "",
            "SharedByUser": null,
            "SharedWithUsers": null,
            "UniqueId": "086ea534-c726-43c1-bfbe-c2f3dbed0ce2",
            "WebId": "2093f273-4f6b-4806-ba5f-a8fcdf036336"
        },....

Any guidance or advice on how to approach this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Steps I've Taken:

Set up SP.ChangeQuery to include all change types (Add, Update, Rename, Move).
Attempted to retrieve additional details using GetItemById, but it doesn't give me the old path information.

